# How to redirect Google Chrome users to an error page

Tags: php, google-chrome

A part of my page does not work on Google Chrome. 
So how do I send Google Chrome users to an error page with PHP because I don't know how to tell which browser the user is using.

I am quite new to php, so how do I go about checking which browser ther client is using, then I guess I use header("page"); die(); .

Comment: So fix the page. This is a dumb approach

Comment: be clear with your codes.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false
 || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'CriOS') !== false) {
    header("Location: chrome_error_page.php");
} else {
    echo "Hey! You use another browser.. :)";
}
```

The above code detects if the user user Chrome. If it use Chrome is redirected to a page. Else you only show a message.

** CriOS - is the Chrome from the iOS.